# Get user info from ACL in parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to get user info from the ACL in cloud code.

```
console.log(request.object.getACL())
```

returns me this...

```
{"JEuS4iJ7lE":{"read":true},"MVrr5lrUwc":{"read":true,"write":true}}
```

How to get the user info from the above user objectId.

Comment: What does the parse.com API documentation say about this? What is "the user info" in parse.com?

Comment: [user-querying](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-querying) can be done in parse cloudcode. Looking for a way to get user info from above user objectId which is returned by the ACL.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Though this thread is super old, I'm sure this is how you would accomplish what you're looking for.

```
var ids = [];
var permissions = request.object.getACL().permissionsById;
for (var id in permissions) {
    ids.push(id);
}
```

That would give you an array of all the ids that have an ACL registered with the object that you can then use to query, etc. you can even refine it a little i.e.

```
var ids = [];
var permissions = request.object.getACL().permissionsById;
for (var id in permissions) {
    if (id.read != true) {
        return;
    }
    ids.push(id);
}
```

to get only users with read permission.

Comment: Hi should not be "id.read" this is incorrect. Should be `request.object.getACL().permissionsById[id].read`

Answer (score -1):

Please try this variant:

```
request.object.getACL().permissionsById[*userId*]
```